# dynamic web form, is there pattern or sample application

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, webforms

I have dynamic form about posting room ad and first option is:

Room in: In flat or In dorm

according the choice, other fields set up.
I don't want to do this hard-code, for the sake of maintenance
plus, there is validation issue while creating and editing.

can you suggest any sample work for this kind of dynamic form, including maybe html helper, object oriented, validator.

[attached image is raw version!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywzqS.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to put each form inside an user control (.ascx) and then load the control dynamically.
If you use a model-view-presenter approach, each user control can have it's own presenter and deal with the details.
I imagine that it must be another way to split a view in parts, but using an user control seems to be the most simple way of doing it.

Comment: You can use custom controls for this problem too, as there is no restriction in what you put inside of it. I often use this approach to break up complex views in smaller parts (and I do use the MVP pattern). You could put your controls inside of a MultiView, and then show the one you need.